# After migrating Drupal site, saving the admin pages re-directs to old url

Tags: drupal-6, migration

I recently migrated a drupal website to a new domain name. The site works fine with one problem . Each time I try to save any data on any of the admin pages , I end up getting redirected to the old url. I have tried a lot to search and find an answer to this problem .. but to no avail. Kindly help .

THanks

Comment: where is the programming question ?

Answer (score 0):

presumably you can set the domain in a config file somewhere. Look through the drupal settings.

failing that check for redirects in your Apache/IIS configuration.

Comment: I have added the base_url to settings.php and also modified the rewrite rules in .htaccess file by uncommenting and adding Rewrite base/ however neither of the things helped. This is the first time that I have faced such a strange error while migrating.